# How to use SwipeRefreshLayout in app targeting API level 14?

Tags: android, android-support-library

Google recently added the [SwipeRefreshLayout](http://developer.android.com/intl/zh-cn/reference/android/support/v4/widget/SwipeRefreshLayout.html) to the support library.

What's the most straightforward and proper way to be able to use this in an app that is targeting API level 14 that has previously been using the regular APIs for things like fragments?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since it's in the support library, you can simply include the library and use it. If you are referring to whether or not it can work with native Fragment instead of Fragment provided by the support library, it can.

It basically is just a decorator over a ListView or a ScrollView, you can follow the tutorial here: http://antonioleiva.com/swiperefreshlayout/